# namespace usage

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I'm trying to start using namespaces the correct (or at least best) way.

The first thing I tried to do was to avoid putting `using namespace xxx;` at the beginning of my files. Instead, I want to `using xxx::yyy` as locally as possible.

Here is a small program illustrating this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;

   srand(time(0));

   for(int i=0; i<10;++i)
      cout << rand() % 100 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

If I omit the lines `using std::cout;` or `using std::endl`, the compiler will complain when I'm trying to use `cout` or `endl`.

But why is this not needed for `srand`, `rand` and `time` ? I'm pretty sure they are in `std`, because if I try to specifically pour `std::` in front of them, my code is working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use cstdlib et al. the names in them are placed in both the global and the std:: namespaces, so you can choose to prefix them with std:: or not. This is seen as a feature by some, and as a misfeature by others.

Comment: \*cough\* misfeature \*cough\*

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to know, take a close look at the `ctime` and `cstdlib` headers.  They were built backwards-compatible.

Note: all this `using` vs. `using namespace` business is about readability.  If your IDE would allow to just not *show* the namespaces when you don't want to see them, you wouldn't need these constructs...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to omit using and just have the std::cout  every time just to maintain readability. although this is probably only useful in larger projects

Comment: I second this - I also prefer writing the full namespace everywhere (even for small projects).

Comment: And if something is particularly unpleasant and used alot then typedef it to something shorter

Answer (score 0):

As long as we on the subject, there's also a thing called [Koenig Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup) which allows you to omit a namespace identifier before a function name if the arguments it take come from the same namespace.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void f(int i){std::cout << i << " ";}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::vector<int> t;
   // for_each is in the std namespace but there's no *std::* before *for_each*
   for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), f); 
   return 0;
}
```

Well, it's not related directly but I though it may be useful.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed by the standard that `std::vector::iterator` is in the std namespace. It could be in some implementation-defined namespace, or it could be a raw pointer. So I realise this is only an example, but I don't think it's a good habit.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - I didn't say it's a good thing it's a thing we should be aware of :-)

Comment: Is that a result of koenig lookup. If the iterators were pointers to an array of int then it would fail? Which is another reason to be explicit about the std:: as you may end up with for_each() from some other jokers namespace.

Comment: Well, if "some other joker" wrote the iterator, the theory is that they probably know how best to implement `for_each` for that iterator. It's only really `swap` that's commonly overloaded via ADL, to the point that it's basically wrong to call `std::swap` explicitly (on objects in general, I mean. Iterators you expect to be cheaply copyable). There are some iterator/algorithms combos which could in theory benefit, though: implementing `find` for `std::set::iterator` springs to mind, but for some reason the standard didn't go there.