# Scope of C libraries in C++ - <X.h> vs <cX>

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

The C++ Programming Language : Special Edition states on page 431 that...

`For every header < X.h > defining part of the C standard library in the global namespace and also in namespace std, there is a header < cX > defining the same names in the std namespace only.`

However, when I use C headers in the < cX > style, I don't need to qualify the namespace. For example...

```
#include <cmath>
void f() {
  double var = sqrt( 17 );
}
```

This would compile fine. Even though the book says that using the < cX > header defines names in the std namespace only, you are allowed to use those names without qualifying the namespace. What am I missing here?

P.S. Using the GNU.GCC compiler

Comment: What is your compiler - many compilers do not conform exactly

Comment: I'm using the GNU.GCC compiler

Comment: Which version? 3.x is too old IIRC.

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116226/namespace-usage/2116289#2116289 asked here 6 hours ago.

Comment: @Neil:  Doesn't look like an exact duplicate to me.  The older question is about header namespaces in general, this one about where C header names go in namespaces.

Comment: @David "But why is this not needed for srand, rand and time ? I'm pretty sure they are in std, because if I try to specifically pour std:: in front of them, my code is working fine." looks like the same question to me.

Comment: I'm sorry if the questions are similar, though I think exact duplicate is strong wording. The title of the question was namespace usage, which even if I had seen the title of the topic I wouldn't have looked in it because of how vague it is. You obviously know about it because you answered the question.

Comment: In addition, the answers to this question provided a completely different set of information than the other question. StackOverflow has just gained a new flux of information for users to find. I can only see this as a benefit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stephan T. Lavavej, a member of the MSVC team, addresses the reality of this situation (and some of the refinements to the standard) in this comment on one of his blog postings (http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/08/28/the-mallocator.aspx#8904359):

> > also, `<cstddef>`, `<cstdlib>`, and `std::size_t` etc should be used!
>
> I used to be very careful about that. C++98 had a splendid dream wherein `<cfoo`> would declare everything within namespace std, and `<foo.h>` would include `<cfoo>` and then drag everything into the global namespace with using-declarations. (This is D.5 [depr.c.headers].)
>
> This was ignored by lots of implementers (some of which had very little control over the C Standard Library headers). So, C++0x has been changed to match reality. As of the N2723 Working Paper, http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2723.pdf , now `<cfoo>` is guaranteed to declare everything within namespace std, and may or may not declare things within the global namespace. `<foo.h>` is the opposite: it is guaranteed to declare everything within the global namespace, and may or may not declare things within namespace std.
>
> In reality and in C++0x, including `<cfoo>` is no safeguard against everything getting declared in the global namespace anyways. That's why I'm ceasing to bother with `<cfoo>`.
>
> This was Library Issue 456, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#456 .
>
> (C++0x still deprecates the `<foo.h>` headers from the C Standard Library, which is hilarious.)

I'm in 100% agreement with Lavavej, except I never tried to be very careful about using the `<cfoo>` style headers even when I first started using C++ - the standard C ones were just too ingrained - and there was never any real world problem using them (and apparently there was never any real world benefit to using the `<cfoo>` style headers).

Comment: So using <cfoo> style headers shouldn't hurt portability?

Comment: No, using `<cfoo>` headers shouldn't hurt portability.  You just shouldn't count on the names from that header being excluded from the global namespace.  Because in reality there's a very good chance they'll be there anyway.

Comment: I'm a weird sort of purist and will likely go on using the `<cfoo>` headers, but this is sad to know.

Answer (score 6):

The rule for the C libraries differs from C++ libraries for namespaces

gcc interprets the standard in [Gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt01ch03s02.html) as

> The standard specifies that if one includes the C-style header (<math.h> in this case), the symbols will be available in the global namespace and perhaps in namespace std:: (but this is no longer a firm requirement.) One the other hand, including the C++-style header (<cmath>) guarantees that the entities will be found in namespace std and perhaps in the global namespace.

In the draft C0X++ spec it says in section 17.6.2.3 Headers

> It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected
>   into namespace std by explicit using-declarations

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to fix this without implementing the C library twice.  See [DR 456](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#456), which basically proposes giving up on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "This would compile fine" when it violates the Standard?  Who allows you to use those names without qualifying the namespace?  Have you tested this on a particular implementation and found that it works?

I strongly advise against using some particular non-standard feature because it happens to work on your compiler of choice.  Such things break easily, perhaps with a later version of the same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing using a standards-conformant compiler (or the one you use is configured to be compatible with pre-standard code).