# how to reference Math.h in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, android-ndk

I use this modf() but the compiler says "undefined reference to modf."  I already include math.h file in the project.

I include the path to math.h in project property->General:[Additional Include Directories] which is at "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include."

I also add the linker property, Linker->Input:[Additional Dependencies] which is "libm.so" and I put the path to "libm.so" at Linker->General:[Additional Library Directories] for "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\lib"

Below is the code to call modf()..

```
#include <math.h>
#include "MyMath.h"

double MyMath::testMod(double a, double b)
{
    return modf(a, &b);
}
```

What else I'm missing here?  thanks.

--------------Update Info-------------------

I'm new to Visual Studio 2015 so this must be new feature in VS because the Error List Windows keeps switch between errors.  If I click on certain source file then rebuild the project, the error will show differently based on the selected source file.

So the prior situation to the error above with math.h file, it's my project pulling math.h file in twice.  It pulls from these locations:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include

and

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-19\arch-x86\usr\include

Notice the arch folders they are different because they are 'arch_arm' and 'arch-x86'  Now i don't know why it does that.  I'm just trying to build this project with NDK to use on android device so I want to build with arm.

Comment: Maybe it's really missing? Have you tried other functions from same header?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I do the right-click on the modf() in VS2015 and select "Go To Declaration", the function is in there and I browse to that folder using File Explorer and it's in there.  Also tried to call sqrt() function too, but the same type of message, undedefined.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I update the situations prior to this error above.

Comment: thank you everyone.  my error is fixed now because Android-19 does not work well with Visual Studio 2015.  So I use Android-21 then add "-lm" in to the linker command so all errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cmath header file instead of math.h

For more information you can refer

[C++ - cmath vs math.h (And similar c-prefixed vs .h extension headers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694255/c-cmath-vs-math-h-and-similar-c-prefixed-vs-h-extension-headers)

Comment: i don't have cmath.h file.  I check this directory "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include" but file is not exist.

Comment: It's not a cmath.h ......It is only cmath 
Just try to execute your program by using 

#include<cmath>

Comment: i put #include<cmath> but still the same error.  I change the call to "return std::modf(a,&b) but still the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I update the situations prior to this error above.

Comment: thank you everyone.  my error is fixed now because Android-19 does not work well with Visual Studio 2015.  So I use Android-21 then add "-lm" in to the linker command so all errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including `cmath`.  This reference says `modf` is in `cmath.h`: [cmath at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf).

Also, have tried prefixing with `std` as in `std::modf`?

Comment: There is no `cmath.h`. Only `math.h` and `cmath`.

Comment: i don't have file cmath.h just like Pete Becker said.  I also tried std::modf() but it says namespace std has no member modf.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I update the situations prior to this error above.

Comment: thank you everyone.  my error is fixed now because Android-19 does not work well with Visual Studio 2015.  So I use Android-21 then add "-lm" in to the linker command so all errors are gone.