# Should I use std:: when calling cmath functions?

Tags: c++, assembly, std, cmath

This is a two-part question:

If I `#include <cmath>` in my header,
1 - What is the difference between using, say, `std::log10()` and `log10()`?
2 - Why do I get such a different assembly code for one vs the other? (being that `std::log10()` yields significantly less instructions)

Thanks!

```
#include <cmath>

float using_std(float i) {
    return std::log10(i);
}

float not_using_std(float i) {
    return log10(i);
}
```

Assembly (from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/))

```
using_std(float):
        jmp     log10f
not_using_std(float):
        sub     rsp, 8
        cvtss2sd        xmm0, xmm0
        call    log10
        add     rsp, 8
        cvtsd2ss        xmm0, xmm0
        ret
```

I know these instructions are not "actual" assembly, they might be hiding more granular instructions, I just want to know if the difference I'm seeing is relevant to the actual performance of code.

Alright, this makes sense, if I instead `#include <math.h>`, they are the same:

```
using_std(float):
        jmp     log10f
not_using_std(float):
        jmp     log10f
```

Comment: `#include <cmath>` puts the C++ function names in `std::`. It also **might** put them in the global namespace.

Comment: `std::log10(i)` calls `std::log10(float)`. But `log10(i)` calls `log10(double)`. if you want it to be equivalent, you need to call `log10f(i)`. The extra code in `not_using_std` is converting from float to double, calling `log10(double)`, and then converting the resulting double back to float.

Comment: It's note a very well argued answer but I would say yes, use the ```std::``` version. For instance, I add undesired behavior with ```abs``` instead of ```std::abs```, I think regarding unexpected conversions.

Comment: `std::` math functions can be overloaded for particular parameter types. The function in the global namespace have exactly one version same as in C.

Comment: question 1 is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694255/cmath-vs-math-h-and-similar-c-prefixed-vs-h-extension-headers

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should include `<cmath>` and use `std::`. That way, you are guarantee that all overloads of the math functions for different argument types will be considered.

What you are seeing is that `std::log10(i)` uses the `float` overload of `log10`, while `log10(i)` uses the `double` overload.

It isn't even guaranteed that `log10(i)` will work at all if you only included `<cmath>` and it is unspecified which overloads will be declared in the global namespace scope by it.

To guarantee that the global overload is available you need to include `<math.h>` instead, which is guaranteed to make all overloads of `std::log10` available in the global namespace scope (but not necessarily in `std::`). So with only that include you should *not* use `std::`.

The standard recommends that only source files which need to also be valid ISO C should use the `<math.h>` header and that other C++ sources should use the `<cmath>` header and consequently also `std::`. See [support.c.headers.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.c.headers#general-1.sentence-3) in the current draft.

When you call the `double` overload, because your argument type and function return type are `float`, there needs to be a type conversion before and after the call, which is where the extra instructions come from.

Comment: That's very clear, also check "EDIT 2", if using `<math.h>` as you said, in that particular compiler, the float overload is available in both uses

Comment: @AlexRodrigues Contrary to my original answer, that's actually guaranteed to work as well (https://eel.is/c++draft/support.c.headers#other-1), but I think not a good style when standard library functions are otherwise always members of `std::`.